# IBM x3650 7979-B1U Memory Configuration

Tags: memory, upgrade, ibm-server

Hi we have IBM x3650 7979-B1U server. We have purchased 3 quantities of the following RAM:

(2x 4 GB) PC2-5300 CL5 ECC DDR2 Chipkill FB-DIMM 667

So in total, the server should recognize 24 GiGs of RAM.

We have installed the RAM in DIMS 1,2,3,4,5,6 However the server recognizes only 16 GIGs of RAM, there is also a BIOS startup message about DIM5 pair failed memory test.

We have also tried Installing in DIMS 1,4 2,5 7,10 as recommended in the users guide http://www.istoragenetworks.com/servermanuals/x3650_7979_userguide.pdf

section " Installing a memory module "

But this time it only recognized 12 GIGs of RAM.

Are we installing the RAM correctly or we are missing something? If you could assist it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The server tells you on startup that one of the modules fails the memory test. That typically means that the module is bad.  Depending on the manufacturer, it's not rare for 5%-10% of new modules to fail.  Get an RMA to exchange the module, and pay attention to what those boot-time diagnostics tell you.  And if you don't know how to recognize which module is bad, just insert two at a time to narrow it down.

Comment: Thank you that was it, we pointed out 2 defective DIMM modules, we will get them replaced.